# Race conditions problem, when synchronizing text files using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, posix

Well, I'm starting my studies on POSIX threads in C, and I'm trying to make each thread, read a line of files, up to and well, I managed to make it work using a synchronization through the condition variable, but when reading the first line of the file, two threads can read at the same time causing the race conditions problem, why does this happen? I tested it using valgrind's helgrind tool.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

/*

  $cat file.txt
  test1
  test2
  test3
  test4
  test5
  test6
*/

FILE *fp;

void *func(void) {

      char c;

      fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
      if(!fp) {
          perror("DEBUG: ");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
         printf("TH = %zu CHARACTER = %c\n", pthread_self(), c);
         if(c == '\n') {
              pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            } else {
              pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          }
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 int main(void) {

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *)func, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *)func, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what "race condition problem" means? What exact symptoms are you observing?

Comment: The first line of the file is being read by two threads simultaneously, that is, the mutex is not working on the first line of the file, causing race conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both threads are opening the file and assigning it to `fp`.

After the first thread opens the file and reads the first entry, the next thread opens the file again and reads the first entry.

Fix this by opening the file in the `main` function and passing the `FILE *` as a parameter to the thread function.  This also fixes the thread function by giving it a signature that `pthread_create` expects, namely `void *(*)(void *)`.

```
void *func(void *param) {

      char c;

      FILE *fp = param;
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
         printf("TH = %zu CHARACTER = %c\n", pthread_self(), c);
         if(c == '\n') {
              pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            } else {
              pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          }
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

      pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 int main(void) {

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

      FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
      if(!fp) {
          perror("DEBUG: ");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func, fp);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, func, fp);

    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I don't know how I missed a silly failure, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When your threads enter `func` they both call `fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")`. This means that you could in theory in at any step of reading the file when the `FILE*` pointed to by `fp` gets pulled out from under the thread that ran first.

If each thread needs to read the entire file then you should pull your declaration of `FILE *fp` to where you open the file so it is a local variable. If you take this approach make sure you close both `FILE*`s.

If they should share the pointer as it is currently set up then you need to safely open the file. There are two ways you could accomplish this depending on your needs.

1) You should change the declaration to also set the value to `NULL`. Then inside of `func` move your `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)` up above the call to `fopen()`. Then and only call `fopen()` if `fp == NULL`.

2) You could also move your call to `fopen()` into `main()` before you start the pthreads. This makes it so only the one thread has to worry about getting the file open and it is balanced with your `fclose(fp)` call so you know the scope of `fp` being a valid pointer.

Also as a side note it is generally good practice to join all of your threads. If you are using Valgrind it will complain about thread1 leaking since it isn't joined. For a simple case like this and with how your threads behave it shouldn't matter in this case but it is a good habit to just have from the get go if you are learning about pthreads.